# Exit Property not working in Framer Motion with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, framer-motion, framerjs

**Exit Property not working in Framer Motion with react js Everything is going well but exit motion is not working i am trying this for more than a week please help me!**

Exit Property not working in Framer Motion with react js Everything is going well but exit motion is not working i am trying this for more than a week please help me!I have installed latest version of framer motion "framer-motion": "^10.10.0", But also no response on exit property.

```
import React ,{useEffect , useState ,useRef } from 'react';
import { Box, Grid,CardContent ,CardActionArea,CardMedia, Typography, styled, List, ListItem, createStyles, Card, TextField, Link, Button, TextareaAutosize } from '@mui/material';
import {motion , useScroll,AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import '../Style/app.css'
import axios from 'axios' 
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cancel';



 export default function Carosel({handleClose}) {



  const [post,setpost] = useState([]);

  const getload = async()=>{

  const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/carosel');
  console.log(response. Data);
  console.log(post);
  setpost(response.data);
  console.log(post);

}


  useEffect(()=>{
      getload();
  },[])


const dropIn ={

hidden:{
    y:"100vh",
    opacity:0,
},

visible:{
    y:"0",
    opacity:1,
    transition:{
        duration:1.5,
        type:"spring",
        damping:35,
        stiffness:100,
    },
},

exit:{
    y:"-100vh",
    opacity:0,
    transition:{
        duration:1.5,
        type:"spring",
        damping:35,
        stiffness:100,
    },
},
};



  
return (

<>

  <AnimatePresence mode='wait'>

        <Box
            component={motion.div}
            variants={dropIn}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            exit="exit"
            onClick={(e)=> e.stopPropagation()}
        >

            <Button>
                    <CancelIcon />
            </Button>

          {post. Map(elem)=>{
              return(
                <Box>
                  <Box
                    component='img'
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    src={elem.Image}
                    >
                  </Box>
                  <Typography>
                    {elem.Title}
                  </Typography>
                </Box>

              )
            })
          }
        </Box>
  </AnimatePresence>    
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/##exit-animations):

> Direct children must each have a unique `key` prop so `AnimatePresence` can track their presence in the tree.

If you add a `key` prop to your main `Box` component it should work.